# Angularjs UI Bootstrap Popover - Put html table inside the popover

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using this, [Angular-UI Bootstrap Popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)

And below is my code snnipt:

```
<a href=""
      popover-placement="{{$index < 4 ? 'bottom' : 'left'}}"
      popover-trigger="outsideClick"
      uib-popover-template="'popover_table.html'">
    Click me  
</a>
```

When I click the link, it will show the popover_table.html content in page, it's a table which shows the data returned from backend. When there are too much data returned, The popover_table will show many records, and user need to scroll down inside the table. So They are asking if we can fixed the table header in the popover dialog top when scroll. [Screenshot added below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdRav.png)

So if there are more than 4 records, I need to add scroll-y and keep the table header fixed in the popover top so user can see it all the time when scrolling.
How to implement this feature? position fixed does not work in this case. 
and also, if I add ng-click for `<a>`, then is there a way to execute the ng-click function after the popover shows? I tested and found that ng-click function execute first..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-click then it suppose to be worked if its still fails use $scope.$apply() inside click function

Comment: yes, ng-click works when i click a tag, the problem here is how to make sure angular-ui popover opens first and then execute the ng-click function. Do you have any ideas on this, Thanks. :)

Comment: Add angular customer directive where you can open popover rather than clicking function and then add your clicking functionality over there.